# AUTH NTLM Authentication Format

Tags: exchange, smtp, ntlm

I am a student worker in Enterprise Systems at the university I attend. We are in the process of converting to a new version of Exchange. We are attempting to use telnet to track messages in our test environment but we can not figure how to correctly input AUTH NTLM username/password string. It needs to be converted to base64.

- What would the format be?
- Something like "domain/user password"?
- Sorry if this is not worded correctly, as I am still very new to this. If this is totally wrong, what would be the proper steps to connect on port 587 with ntlm?

Comment: Exchange has a built in message tracking tool. Why are you using telnet?

Answer (score 1):

> What would the format be? Something like "domain/user password"?

Not so simple: NTLM does not transmit passwords in an unencrypted form. [Here is an example](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html#ntlmSmtpAuthentication) SMTP session with NTLM authentication.

Actually, [this document describes in detail the work NTLM](https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html) - I recommend to read for understanding.